# Place Custom Mines in Minesweeper

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to mess around with the minesweeper code, and what I am trying to do is place the mines in specific locations [x,y] so they can spell out a letter once they are detonated. I am using this to page to practice https://codepen.io/joelbyrd/pen/hdHKF , but for some reason I can't get it to work. I tried to modify the randIndex and setting it to [1,1] to just place one mine in the corner but It didnt work. How would I go about doing this?

```
layMines: function() {
        var rowCol,
            cell,   

  i;

        // designate mine spots
        this.designateMineSpots();

        for ( i = 0; i < this.numMines; i++ ) {
            rowCol = this.numToRowCol( this.mineCells[i] );
            cell = this.cells[ rowCol[0] ][ rowCol[1] ];            
            cell.hasMine = true;
            cell.classUncovered = 'mine';
        }
    }, // end layMines()

//-----------------------------------

    // designate unique random mine spots and store in this.mineCells
    designateMineSpots: function() {
        this.safeCells = [];
        this.mineCells = []

        var i,
            randIndex;

        i = this.numCells;
        while ( i-- ) {
            this.safeCells.push( i + 1 );
        }

        i = this.numMines;
        while ( i-- ) {
            randIndex= 
              -~( Math.random() * this.safeCells.length ) - 1;
            this.mineCells.push( this.safeCells[randIndex] );
            this.safeCells.splice( randIndex, 1 ); // remove cell from array of safe cells
        }        
    }, // end designateMineSpots

//-----------------------------------    

    // calculate and set surrounding mine count for a cell
    calcMineCount: function( row, col ) {
        var count = 0,
            cell = this.cells[row][col],
            i, 
            j;

        for (i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
            for (j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++) {
                // applying to surrounding cells, but we skip actual cell
                if (i == row && j == col) { continue; }

                if (this.cells[i][j].hasMine) { count++; }
            }
        }

        cell.numSurroundingMines = count;

        if (!cell.hasMine) { 
            cell.classUncovered = 'mines' + count;
        }
    },

//-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you were modifying `randIndex` to be `[1,1]`, but `randIndex` should be an integer. The following code was modified to place all of the mines along the bottom.

```
// designate unique random mine spots and store in this.mineCells
designateMineSpots: function() {
    this.safeCells = [];
    this.mineCells = []

    var i,
        randIndex;

    i = this.numCells;
    while ( i-- ) {
        this.safeCells.push( i + 1 );
    }

    i = this.numMines;
    while ( i-- ) {
        randIndex= i; // This will put all mines along the bottom rows. 
        this.mineCells.push( this.safeCells[randIndex] );
        this.safeCells.splice( randIndex, 1 ); // remove cell from array of safe cells
    }        
}, // end designateMineSpots
```

It sounds like you also want to be able to change the mine count? Maybe in 'newGame' change the minecount to whatever number you need? In combination with the code above this will place a single mine on the bottom row.

I'm not sure if you ever want to respect the default number of mines for a level? If not you probably don't even need to pass `numMines` to the `newGame` constructor. You can remove all the references to setting it and replace it with the code to calculate how many mines you need to spell out your letter.

```
newGame: function( level, numRows, numCols, numMines, resetting ) {
    var resetting = resetting || false;
    // Note most of the code below was removed to make it clear which change you need. 
   // You only need to add the one line at the bottom of this. 
    ...
    if ( resetting ) {
        ...

        // reset cells    
        for ( i = 1; i <= this.numRows; i++ ) {
            for ( j = 1; j <= this.numCols; j++ ) {
                ...
            }
        }
    } else { // new game (not resetting)

        if ( level == 'custom' ) {
           ...
        } else {
           ...
        }

        this.numMines = 1; // HERE IS THE MODIFICATION TO MINECOUNT YOU NEED
        ...
    }
 }
```

UPDATE: I was asked how `randIndex` is being used to determine which cells to put mines in.

If you look at `designateMineSpots()` you will see that it first creates an array of integers representing all cells (with 0 representing the bottom right) and stores those as the 'safe' cells. 
Then, in the `while(i--)` loop it removes one safe cell (at index `randIndex`) from the array of safe cells and moves it to be a mine cell by putting it in the `mineCells` array.

There are a couple ways to figure out which cells to remove from the `safeCells` and put in `mineCells`, but hopefully the following example gives you some idea.

```
[8][7][6]
[5][4][3]
[2][1][0]
```

In the 3x3 minefield above, to make the letter 'T' you would remove elements 8, 7, 6, 4 and 1 from `safeCells` and move them to `mineCells`. Note that it is probably important to remove them in that descending order, otherwise `safeCells[8]` may not contain the integer 8. For example, if you remove `safeCells[1]` first and splice the array to remove that element as they are doing, then `safeCells[8]` no longer exists, and the integer 8 is contained by `safeCells[7]`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, great explanation! But why does the while ( i-- ) {
            randIndex= i; .. places the mines at the bottom. How would you place it in the top or right in the middle?? Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Cesar I updated my answer to try and help answer that. Basically, `safeCells` is an array containing integers that map to a cell in the grid, with 0 representing the bottom right corner. So you will want to walk that array and remove any elements mapping to a cell that you want a mine in, and put that element in `mineCells` instead. Hope that helps you. Let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This worked. I tried it on  7X7 matrix. And I took out elements this.mineCells.push( this.safeCells[49,48,47,46,45,44,43,39,32,25,18,11,4] ) and put it in the minecell= []; And I get a letter T :D .....but it's upside down lol. Any idea why? PS. Again Thanks for being so helpful !

Comment: Just changed it to this.mineCells = [46,39,32,25,18,11,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] and it works perfect now! I get a letter T :)